# JavaScript multiple auto count for cashier apps?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page like this:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ph75fggo/]
[http://jsfiddle.net/ph75fggo/5/]//more reliable sample
```

And I tried to make a simple cashier apps, with help of JavaScript make an auto count on both rows and columns.

This is the result I want to get:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrz8bc10/

My Final Trying: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ph75fggo/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is not drawing the clear picture of your requirement. As far as I understand, you need to have a gross amount after deducting the discount for each row and the total discounted and net amounts at the end.

First thing that you should do is to assign a common class to each of the child of every tr. It makes your JS code a lot simpler. Otherwise you need write some extra LOC to select specific element.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' class="amount" id='harga2' value='250000' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="discount" id='diskon2' value='' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="grossAmount" id='total2' value='' /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' class="amount" id='harga2' value='250000' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="discount" id='diskon2' value='' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="grossAmount" id='total2' value='' /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' class="amount" id='harga2' value='250000' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="discount" id='diskon2' value='' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="grossAmount" id='total2' value='' /></td> 
</tr>
```

After that you can use the following function:

```
function myFunction(){
    var amounts = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
    var discounts = document.getElementsByClassName("discount");
    var gAmounts = document.getElementsByClassName("grossAmount");
    var lv,rowSum,totDis=0,totAmount=0;
    for(lv=0;lv>gAmounts.length;lv++){
        rowSum += (parseInt(amounts[lv].value)-parseInt(discounts[lv].value));
        totAmount += rowSum;
        totDis += parseInt(discounts[lv].value);
        gAmounts[lv].value = totAmount;
    }
}
```

But if you don't want change your HTML, Then you can use the following code:

```
function myFunc(){
    var lv,rowSum,totDis=0,totAmount=0;
    var TRs = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childNodes; //assuming that the table is the first one on your page.
    var lv;
    for(lv=1;lv<tab.length;lv++){ // starting the counter with 1 as the first child of the table contains headings
        rowSum += (parseInt(TRs[lv][0].value)-parseInt(TRs[lv][1].value));
        totAmount += rowSum;
        totDis += parseInt(TRs[lv][1].value);
        TRs[lv].value = rowSum;
    }
}
```

Comment: My Better tried : [jsfiddle.net/SuryaTanamas/vb2cb1tm/](http://jsfiddle.net/SuryaTanamas/vb2cb1tm/)... but it so crowd to using nearly same agreement repeatly

Comment: @SuryaTanamas, The code you have written contain redundancy a lot. Good programmers never do that. :)

Comment: I am self learned programmer, I am still so novice... because that I always asked here, any problem I found during programming

Answer (score 0):

You were getting the elements with ids 'id1' and 'id2' whereas there are no such elements present in your html with those ids, they should be 'harga1' and 'diskon1'. Also, when you write your JS in a function, make sure to call it at the end, but you don't need to write it in a function in this specific case, so here is your solution:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

for(var i=1; i<rows; i++){
    var harga = parseInt(document.getElementById('harga'+i).value);
    var diskon = parseInt(document.getElementById('diskon'+i).value);
    var total = harga - diskon;
    document.getElementById('total'+i).value = total;
}
```

Get the number of rows, then keep getting the harga and diskon values one by one.. harga1, harga2, harga3.. `('harga'+i)` subtract their values and put them in total1, total2 and total 3.. this will work if you add more rows as well..

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/ph75fggo/3/)**

Comment: the counting it's not working 'total = harga - diskon'

Comment: what do you mean by counting? it's subtracting diskon from harga in each row and displaying result in total column.

Comment: it's not working at all, like i said before it auto-count function

Comment: you want to count the number of rows and columns??

Comment: ok with name 'harga' you maybe dificult to understand. how about to make auto-counting 'how much to pay for each invoice(rows) ?' and to auto-count each payment into total payment that display bottom of table

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the JSFiddle here:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ph75fggo/4/]
```

This is just one approach at what you are trying to do, where I changed your code as little as possible, and still uses hard coded variable names (instead of the above answer that automatically iterates over all rows). You can use my answer to help simply extend your cashier application.

Comment: it's not I mean, it about auto-count on both rows and columns using onchange() or onkeyup()

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this link?
you can change use the parameters if you want

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Harga</td>
            <td>Total Diskon</td>
            <td>Total Bayar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' id='harga1' onchange="dynamic()" value='250000' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='diskon1' value='50' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='total1' value='' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' id='harga2' value='250000' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='diskon2' value='0' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='total2' value='0' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' id='harga3' value='250000' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='diskon3' value='0' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='total3' value='0' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    <script>


function dynamic(){
  var harga1 = document.getElementById('harga1').value;
  var diskon1 = document.getElementById('diskon1').value/100;
  var totalharga = harga1 - (harga1 * diskon1);

  document.getElementById("total1").value = totalharga;
}
    </script>
    </html>
```